# Unable to detect IGPU with OpenVINO on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: python, ubuntu, gpu, ubuntu-22.04, openvino

Unable to detect IGPU with OpenVINO on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

CPU: Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 v3 @ 3.40GHz × 8

Graphic: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics P4600/P4700 (HSW GT2)

I have follow the "openvino_notebooks/notebooks/108-gpu-device" (https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/108-gpu-device)

my code

```
import openvino as ov

core = ov.Core()
core.available_devices
```

output

```
['CPU']
```

I followed the setup tutorial in a GitHub repository to configure OpenVINO to utilize my integrated GPU (iGPU). However, despite following the instructions, my integrated GPU is still not being detected.

```
sudo apt-get install -y ocl-icd-libopencl1 intel-opencl-icd intel-level-zero-gpu level-zero
```

[Screenshot after running the commned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APK4M.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I have a CPU with an integrated GPU (iGPU). Even after following all the required steps as per the tutorial, OpenVINO is unable to detect my iGPU.